# Embed Fonts using @font-face in CSS across domains in flex4.11

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4, font-face, flex4.10

I am trying to Embed fonts in External css file using @font-face in flex4.11 sdk. The code snippet is like this,

MyOwnFontStyle.css:

```
 @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
 @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx";
 @font-face {
    src:url("font/GOTHICB.ttf");
    fontFamily: myFontFamily;
    embedAsCFF: true;
    fontWeight: bold;
 }

 s|VGroup {
    fontFamily: myFontFamily;
    fontSize: 15;
 }
```

It builds successfully without any errors. But when am launching application it throws runtime execption like below,

ArgumentError: Error #1508: The value specified for argument font is invalid.
    at flash.text::Font$/registerFont()
    at MyOwnFontStyle/setStyleDeclarations()
    at MethodInfo-19757()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at ModuleInfoProxy/moduleEventHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at ModuleInfo/readyHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/update()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameHandler()
    at mx.core::FlexModuleFactory/docFrameListener()

If anyone come across this kind of things, Kindly share your ideas to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone facing the same problem, do forcefully include the below statements in your main application.

import mx.core.EmbeddedFontRegistry;

private var embeddedFontRegistry:EmbeddedFontRegistry;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you setted wrong url.
Try to set

```
src:url("/font/GOTHICB.ttf");
```

also note that the "font" directory need to be located in "src" directory

Or try to use some new font, maybe

> GOTHICB.ttf

file is non-working

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now its working fine for me. If anyone facing the same problem, do forcefully including "import mx.core.EmbeddedFontRegistry;
private var embeddedFontRegistry:EmbeddedFontRegistry;" in your main application.

Comment: If this answer was helpful for you then can you please approve and up it?